# React data pull not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to build a table component that changes based on what is passed in for headers and rows.

I have been following the fb react tutorials and I have hit a road block I have looked on here and did some changes but nothing is working.

Here is my HTML page that gets the generated content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/etdsolutions/sweetalert/sweetalert.css?<?= assetCacheQueryStr() ?>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/vendor/etdsolutions/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js?<?= assetCacheQueryStr()?>"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/sorttable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <title>React</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadboardContainer"></div>

        <!-- Import the table react setup. -->
        <script type="text/babel" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I have the external react script in the test.js file which is this.

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      results: [],
      columns: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      this.setState({
        results: result['resultRows'],
        columns: $.makeArray(result['resultCols'])
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },
  render: function() {
    // Set array for rows.
    var rows = [];
    var header = [];

    this.state.columns.map(function(cols) {
      header.push(<TableColumns data={cols.cols} key={cols.id} />);
    });

    this.state.results.map(function(result) {
      rows.push(<TableRow data={result.rows} key={result.id} />);
    });

    // Loop through head to get columns.
    /*this.props.columns.forEach(function(cols) {
      header.push(<TableColumns data={cols.cols} key={cols.id} />);
    });

    // Loop through the returned rows and display.
    this.props.results.forEach(function(result) {
      rows.push(<TableRow data={result.rows} key={result.id} />);
    });*/


    // Return the table.
    return (
      <table className="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          {header}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

// Set up columns
var TableColumns = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var colNodes = this.props.data.map(function(col, i){
      return (
        <th key={i}>{col}</th>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {colNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

// Set up row
var TableRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rowNodes = this.props.data.map(function(row, i){
      return (
        <td key={i}>{row}</td>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {rowNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var futureContainer = document.getElementById('loadboardContainer');

ReactDOM.render(<Table source="getTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
```

As you can see I have the commented out part of what used to be the props calls to the table. Now that I am trying to get the information from another file it looks like on here I have to use state.

On the other file this is what I have. Its just an array of array to return data before I actually query the stuff.

```
<?php
  // Start the session.
  session_start();

  // Set Variables.
  $returned = array(); // Returns results

  $returned['resultRows'][0] = array();
  $returned['resultRows'][0]['id'] = 10221;
  $returned['resultRows'][0]['rows'] = array("654221", "2016-03-26", "Customer 1", "98755/54622", "Carrier 1", "Driver 1", "2016-03-28", "TX - IN", "DRY", "1240", "", "", "This is a test note");

  $returned['resultRows'][1] = array();
  $returned['resultRows'][1]['id'] = 10223;
  $returned['resultRows'][1]['rows'] = array("654221", "2016-03-26", "Customer 1", "98755/54622", "Carrier 2", "Driver 2", "2016-03-28", "TX - IN", "DRY", "1240", "", "", "This is a test note2");

  $returned['resultCols']['id'] = 100;
  $returned['resultCols']['cols'] = array("PO Number", "Load Date", "Customer(s)", "Customer PO", "Carrier", "Driver", "Delivery Date", "Lane", "Temp", "Weight", "Attention Date", "ND Date", "Notes");

  echo json_encode($returned);
?>
```

I keep getting an error this.state.columns.map is not a function.
The same is true if I use this.props. So what am I doing wrong on this? I know how to make it work if I statically put in the data and insert that way on the since page but the call is not working.

Comment: You should check that `this.state.columns` is not undefined before you try to map over it.

Comment: Shouldn't it always be defined since its set in the getInitialState? If I alert it, it shows nothing just an empty box but the way their documentation talks it seems like as long and its defined in the getInitialState it is defined.

Comment: Don't use alerts to test code, as can be blocking, try `console.log` instead. you had strings in there before you changed it (which do not have map on their proto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to map a string at the beginning because of async $.get

replace this :

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
     results: '',
     columns: ''
  }
}
```

by this :

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
     results: [],
     columns: []
  }
}
```

EDIT TO MATCH PHP RETURN

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      results: [],
      columns: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      this.setState({
        results: result['resultRows'],
        columns: result['resultCols'].cols
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },
  render: function() {    

    // Return the table.
    return (
      <table className="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <TableColumns data={this.state.columns} />
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.results.map(function(result) {
            rows.push(<TableRow data={result.rows} key={result.id} />);
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

// Set up columns
var TableColumns = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var colNodes = this.props.data.map(function(col, i){
      return (
        <th key={i}>{col}</th>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {colNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

// Set up row
var TableRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rowNodes = this.props.data.map(function(row, i){
      return (
        <td key={i}>{row}</td>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {rowNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var futureContainer = document.getElementById('loadboardContainer');

ReactDOM.render(<Table source="getTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
```

Comment: Oh so react doesnt override variables then? I changed it now its saying the state is undefined.

Comment: React will override variables, but after your request is done. So before he try to map a string. But why this state is undefined ? ...  could you log the results (in the $.get) and then the state (in render() ) ?

Comment: {"resultRows":[{"id":10221,"rows":["654221","2016-03-26","Customer 1","98755\/54622","Carrier 1","Driver 1","2016-03-28","TX - IN","DRY","1240","","","This is a test note"]},{"id":10223,"rows":["654221","2016-03-26","Customer 1","98755\/54622","Carrier 2","Driver 2","2016-03-28","TX - IN","DRY","1240","","","This is a test note2"]}],"resultCols":{"id":100,"cols":["PO Number","Load Date","Customer(s)","Customer PO","Carrier","Driver","Delivery Date","Lane","Temp","Weight","Attention Date","ND Date","Notes"]}}

Comment: I can't believe that `this.state`is undefined ... it's really strange ...

Comment: Yeah I just put in a json.parse and it returns the objects just like I was thinking it would but then after that it gives me that this.state.columns.map is not a function

Comment: can you log this.state before using the map ?

Comment: Object { results: Array[2], columns: Object } This is what it returns. It looks like its grabbing everything I want

Comment: How do I get around that the json.parse is forcing it to become an object and without the json.parse it says the state in undefined

Comment: Also if it makes it any easier you are able to copy that full code and try it on your machine there is not connection or anything outside of it.

Comment: Javascript is different than PHP

something[0] is an array
something['id'] is an object

Comment: Well that did work! Thank you. This React stuff is a little more confusing that it looks. Such a different way of thinking for programming.

Comment: I have updated my answer if you want to take a look ?

Comment: Oh what I did was add $.makeArray(result['resultCols']) where the columns call is in the componentDidMount function and it got rid of the objects so it worked as needed.

Comment: Other than that it looks perfect!

Comment: U don't need to make it an array ;) because you'll never need to have multiple header ^^

Comment: That works too! Thank you so much. I think I am starting to grasp my head around this language.